# $helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper(); causes 'Signed request has an invalid signature.'

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Its too strange. I try to experiment with SDK 5.

At first I open
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([id,secret,graph)

as next just
$helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();
die;

I receive "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Signed request has an invalid signature.'

Put the die;  before $helper, no error. So I think, it must be from the helper. But its no signed request. It makes me crazy, searched the half day. Someone an Idea?

Comment: Are you using it within a page tab?

Comment: yes, its in a Tab.

Comment: Double-check the app secret. Decoding the signed request uses the secret, so if that is wrong or not the one belonging to the app id, that would likely cause an invalid signature error.